# Issue with Magento 1.9 custom url rewrites

Tags: php, magento, redirect, url-rewriting

I have a site built in Magento 1.9 that has the same page linked differently in different places. In some places it is linked as `/contact-us` and in others it is linked as `/contact-us/`. Magento is treating these as two different pages. For SEO purposes we want these two to appear as the same single page.

I tried implementing a custom URL Rewrite in the Magento admin and set the request path to: `contact-us`, and the target path to: `contact-us/`, and this effectively adds the `/` to the end of the path, but somehow this ends up triggering a redirect loop.

Can anyone advise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From everything I could find this trailing slash issue could not be fixed using the URL Rewrite section in the Magento admin menu.

I was able to solve this by directly modifying the root `.htaccess` file and adding the following:

```
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !(.*)/$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !\.(gif|jpg|png|jpeg|css|js)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1/ [L,R=301]
```

Sharing in case this is helpful for anyone else.